# LICENSE file in R package including third party library

Tags: r, r-package

I have a very specific question regarding the licensing of my R package.

Here is the details: I have an R package under the MIT license so the DESCRIPTION file contains the field `License: MIT + file LICENSE` and the LICENSE file contains the following required fields:

```
YEAR: yyyy
COPYRIGHT HOLDER: xx
```

My problem is that my package includes a third party C++ library also under MIT license but with different copyright holder and year information (available in its own LICENSE file shipped with the library).

How can I edit the LICENSE file of my package to have both copyright information? Am I supposed to merge them without specifying that I developed one package and only included another lib?

For instance, the package RcppEigen (which has a similar structure with an included third party C++ lib) specifies the different copyrights in the LICENSE file (but the license is different and not MIT, thus the requirement regarding the LICENSE file is not the same).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about licensing are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing).

Comment: The question was not about the choice of a license per se, but about the structure of a R package including codes distributed under different license/copyrights.

Answer (score 1):

I was given a solution, to use a detailed file `COPYRIGHTS`, in the `inst` directory (i.e. `inst/COPYRIGHTS`) so that it is copied at installation, with the following structure:

```
Files: inst/include/xxx/*
Copyright: <year> <name>
License: <license>

Files: *
Copyright: <year> <name>
License: <license>
```

as in RcppEigen actualy (I did not find the `inst/COPYRIGHTS` file at first).